# Squared edge lengths

Tags: adjectives, numbers, mathematics

Can I also say:

> The energy is based on edge length squared.

Adjectives usually go before a noun, but maybe here 'squared' can be treated also as a verb or a postpositive adjective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lexico from Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/definition/squared) describes "squared" as a postpositive adjective, i.e. an adjective that follows the noun that it modifies: "(of a linear unit of measurement) converted to a unit of area equal to a square whose side is of the unit specified.".

The OED's entry is older; it has **squared** as an adjective with meanings including (#2) "Multiplied by itself. Also figurative." Most of the examples precede the noun being modified (e.g. "squared number", "squared term") but there is also a postpositive example in a metaphorical sense "spider squared" meaning spider to an extreme degree (more scary and "spidery" than most spiders).

English has many adjectives that are commonly used postnominally/postpositively ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective)), such as "redux", "galore", "incarnate", and "abreast". Of these examples "redux" and "galore" both refer to number, while the likes of "abreast" and "akimbo" refer to geometric arrangement.

Less conclusively, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/squared) also refers to "squared" as a postpositive adjective.

Ref to OED: "square, v." OED Online. Oxford University Press, March 2021. Web. 31 May 2021. Tagged "This entry has not yet been fully updated (first published 1915; latest version published online April 2020)."

Answer (score 1):

> The energy is based on edge length *squared*.

This sounds like a a [reduced relative clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=reduced%20relative%20clause)...

i.e.

> The energy is based on edge length (which is) squared.

This  is [a type of ellipsis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ellipsis) which   I think many here  would call a ***whiz-deletion***.

> The rule called Whiz-Deletion by linguists (from the fact that it deletes a Wh-word plus a form of be, quite often is; a monosyllabic variant of "Wh-is deletion"), when applied to a relative clause, creates a bare verb phrase without a tensed verb, but with whatever is left after the deletion.

[John Lawler on WordWizard.com](http://wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=24650)

So I think "squared" in the post-nominal   could be classified as a  ***(bare) verb phrase.***

---

In the case of (from your title)....

***squared edge length***

This could be read  as an Adjective + Noun combination i.e. "a squared edge".

But others   might read that as ...

> an edge which has been squared

...which once again seems to be a reduced clause, whiz-deletion, etc. I think some linguists have pointed out that the  English pre-positioning of adjectives might actually derive from that very idea.  Apart from that then we have the problem of how to regard "edge" with "length"...

---

All of that said, the post-nominal placement reflects spoken Mathematics... which usually includes the exponent in the post-positive position. *Why* this is done would be an interesting question: is it based on Arabic and Greek?

Comment: As always, I am open to constructive criticism...

Comment: Any opposing viewpoint would need to argue that it is an adjective here. I am looking forward to that **answer...**

Comment: I think the reason why this is the common practice in mathematics is that it matches the ordering in equation form.  **E=mc²** is read as "Ee equals em cee squared."